# jQuery, thumbnail opacity

Tags: jquery, opacity

I want to do a photo gallery in jQuery, to do that I want the opacity of the first thumbnail in 1, and all the other thumbnails in 0.5, and as soon as my mouse is above a thumbnail, the opacity of this very one will be 1 and when my mouse will be out, the opacity will be back to 0.5.
So I did all of that, the problem is that I don't want this "mouseover", "mouseout" code for the thumbnail i clicked in, so what i did is:

```
var selector = $('.thumb:first');
```

then

```
 $('.thumb').click(function() {
    selector = $(this);
  $(this).css('opacity','1');
```

$('.thumb').css('opacity','0.5');
      });

and

```
$('.thumb').mouseover(function() {
    if($(this) != selector){
    $(this).css('opacity','1');
    }
});

$('.thumb').mouseout(function() {
    if($(this) != selector){
    $(this).css('opacity','0.5');
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work, as soon as my mouse is leaving the last thumbnail i clicked on, the opacity of the thumbnail is going to 0.5 instead of staying to 1

Comment: selector != $(this) will always evaluate to true.  Try adding classes to the thumbs and comparing them that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class to the clicked thumb and check if the thumb has the class on the mouseover event.

```
$('.thumb').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $(this).css('opacity','1');
});

$('.thumb').mouseover(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
        $(this).css('opacity','1');
    }
});

$('.thumb').mouseout(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
        $(this).css('opacity','0.5');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something CSS can handle for you! See `first-child` or `first-of-type` psuedo selectors. By moving presentation logic like this out of your JS and into CSS, you're helping yourself and your fellow developers out in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`selector != $(this)`

will always evaluate to `true`, because they are separate object instances created with the `new` keyword.  So, in the same vein,

`$(this) != $(this)`

will always evaluate to `true`, as well.

Try adding classes to the thumbs and comparing them that way.

```
var classStr = $('.thumb:first').attr('class');
```

and then in your event handlers:

```
if ($(this).attr('class') !== classStr) {
    // elements are not the same
}
```

Answer (score -1):

JS:

```
$('.thumb:first').addClass("selected");

$('.thumb').click(function() {
  $('.thumb.selected').removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

CSS:

```
.thumb { opacity: 0.5; }
.thumb:hover { opacity: 1; }
.thumb.selected { opacity: 1; }
.thumb.selected:hover { opacity: 1; }
```

​
​